# Problem in aligning the bottom of the top relative layout to let its bottom reached the top of the fixed bottom layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Help, I've been trying to fix this the whole day but still could not do it.

I am trying to make the top layout(fixed) which included a scrollview to have its bottom touching the top of the bottom layout(fixed) but it just couldn't work. I am trying to fill/spread the center white layout to cover all the black background at the back if that make sense? until its bottom stick with the "answer a question" view which is fixed at the bottom.
[image]

Is there anyway to fix it if I insist to use constraint layout as the base layout? I figured that it might be easier to achieve this with a base relative layout but I've heard that contraint layout would be better to suit all devices sizes, but sometimes it's really frustrating when something like this happened.

Thank you in advanced.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient0"
    tools:context=".AddNoteActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/aboveLayoutaddnote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomLayoutAddnote">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleAddNote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/im_fell_dw_pica"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:text="Write today's story"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollviewAdd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/titleAddNote">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/topradwhiterec"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="title" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="description" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="advice for self" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Question here" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="answer" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayoutAddnote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/aboveLayoutaddnote">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/buttonsLayout"
            android:background="@color/reflectcolor"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/whitequestion" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionBtnAddnote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ANSWER A QUESTION"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:src="@drawable/save" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because aboveLayoutaddnote has layout_height="wrap_content". That prevents the layout from stretching and filling the available space.

The solution is to set layout_height="0dp" in aboveLayoutaddnote. That will allow the constraints to act as intended.

More information about constraints in the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks! will try later :)